# htaccess file is not working properly in Laravel on linux

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm working on a Laravel project. I'm Removing "/public" from URL but it's only work on `welcome` page, other page like `/login`,`/register` is doesn't work properly. it's shows an error.

> The requested URL /GME/login was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

but when I use `public/index.php` in URL it's working.

> http://localhost/GME/public/index.php/login

Here, is my `root` `.htaccess` file code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] #relative substitution
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

and here is my `/public/.htaccess` file code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

> note: i'm using linux elementary OS loki version
>   [image: Directory Structure]

Comment: could you share your folder structure?

Comment: like as `laravel` project folder structure.

Comment: where did you setup the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`? Is it the `public` folder? or the root of the laravel project? Your document root should be the `public` folder.

Comment: @SakibulAlam i'm update my question please see the directory structure

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this to the **GME** directory .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: in `root` directory `.htaccess`  or `public/.htaccess`?